# Storing keys of an associative array in d

Tags: arrays, d

Example code:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    auto a = ["one":1, "two":2, "three":3];
    writeln(a);
}
```

But output:

```
["three":3, "one":1, "two":2]
```

By default, D optimizes storing keys. How to disable or reimplement it?

Comment: What do you mean by "storing", was it intended as "sorting" lexicographically?

Comment: or just in order of adding the keys?

Comment: yes,order of adding the keys.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're complaining that the order that the pairs was printed out doesn't match the insertion order? An associate array is a hash table. There is no order to it. The equivalent type in C++11 is called `unordered_map`, specifically because hash tables have no order. How key/value pairs are placed in the table is entirely based on the hashes of the keys. The order that they're in the table could even change entirely if the table gets rehashed. In order for a hash table to retain insertion order for printing or any other purpose, it would have to maintain a separate list of the keys in insertion order, which would be additional overhead, which most people don't need, so it wouldn't make sense for that to be built into the core AA implementation.

So, if you want to maintain the insertion order, you're going to have to maintain it yourself in a separate data structure - e.g. keep an array of all of the keys that have been inserted into the hash table where you append the key to the array when you add it to the AA and remove it from the array when you remove that key from the AA.

Here's one possible implementation of printing the key/value pairs of an AA in a particular order:

```
import std.stdio;

auto orderKeys(int[string] hashTable, string[] keys)
{
    import std.array;

    static struct Range
    {
        @property bool empty() @safe const pure nothrow { return _keys.empty; }

        @property auto front() @trusted const pure
        {
            static struct PrettyPrintTuple
            {
                string toString() @trusted pure
                {
                    import std.string;
                    return format(`"%s":%s`, key, value);
                }

                string key;
                int value;
            }

            return PrettyPrintTuple(_keys.front, _hashTable[_keys.front]);
        }

        void popFront() @safe pure nothrow
        {
            _keys.popFront();
        }

        int[string] _hashTable;
        string[] _keys;
    }

    return Range(hashTable, keys);
}

void main()
{
    auto a = ["one":1, "two":2, "three":3];
    writeln(orderKeys(a, ["one", "two", "three"]));
}
```

Rather than maintaining an AA and an array separately, it would be cleaner to have a wrapper type which held both the AA and the array where you called functions on it to add, remove, or access elements, taking care of managing the array so that it matched exactly the set of keys currently in the AA in insertion order (whereas the range above assumes that all of the keys are in the AA), but I'll leave that exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

D associative array does not preserve insert order.
Some more information (and implementation) you can find here:

http://forum.dlang.org/thread/xbanhtkvrizyqjcibsck@forum.dlang.org#post-51F9327D.2020704:40esperanto.org.ar

http://forum.dlang.org/thread/dfyowpjhdaemhxhepfmk@forum.dlang.org?page=3

BTW. I have some better implementation of OrderedAA, so if you wish I can make it public (If I found it :))